# Mostrar imágen en ImageView Android Studio desde sqlLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-imageview

Buenas, estoy realizando una aplicación muy sencilla que guarda imágenes en SQLite para luego mostrarlas en un ListItem con celdas personalizadas.

Cada imagen tiene un nombre una descripción y una ID, los cuales guardo también en SQLite. El problema es que la imagen no se muestra pero el nombre, descripción e ID que escribes si.

He probado de todo y ya no se me ocurre nada más. Os dejo el código a ver si me podéis echar una mano..

```
public void cargarLista()
{
    db = usdbh.getReadableDatabase();
    if (db != null)
    {
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Notas ORDER BY codigo ASC", null);
        //Nos aseguramos de que existe al menos un registro
        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
            int cuenta = c.getCount();
            datosLista = new Nota[cuenta];
            int i = 0;
            do {
                datosLista[i] = new Nota();
                datosLista[i].setCodigo(c.getInt(0));
                datosLista[i].setNombre(c.getString(1));
                datosLista[i].setContenido(c.getString(2));
                datosLista[i].setImagen(c.getBlob(3)); // -> Esto devuelve algo parecido a [SH21D398D  es solo un ejemplo
                i++;
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            AdaptadorUsuarios adaptador = new AdaptadorUsuarios(this);
            lstLista.setAdapter(adaptador);
            adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else
        {
            // Haremos desaparecer el último item 'borrando' el adaptador
            lstLista.setAdapter(null);
        }
    }
}
class AdaptadorUsuarios extends ArrayAdapter
{
    Activity context;
    AdaptadorUsuarios(Activity context)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.listitem_nota, datosLista);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View item = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (item == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_nota, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.codigo = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.LblCodigo);
            holder.nombre = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.LblNombre);
            holder.email = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.LblEmail);
            holder.imagen = (ImageView)item.findViewById(R.id.LblImagen);
            item.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)item.getTag();
        }
        // Añadiremos el contenido de la nota a nuestro listitem personalizado.

        // Esta línea está activa para mostrar la ID en SQL mientras se desarolla la APP.
        holder.codigo.setText(datosLista[position].getCodigo() + "");

        holder.nombre.setText(cortar(datosLista[position].getNombre(), 37));
        holder.email.setText(cortar(datosLista[position].getContenido(), 55));

        // Obtenemos el BLOB de la imagen y la creamos en bitmap
        byte[] icono = datosLista[position].getImagen();
        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(icono);
        Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        holder.imagen.setImageBitmap(theImage);
        return(item);
    }

    public String cortar(String str, int len)
    {
        if (str.length() > len) {
            return str.substring(0, len) + "...";
        } else {
            return str;
        }
    }
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView codigo;
    TextView nombre;
    TextView email;
    ImageView imagen;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenta convertir tu imagen al formato Bitmap

```
final byte[] photo = 

UserConfig.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhoto();
   if (photo != null) {
      final Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photo, 0, photo.length);
      img.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
    }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415619/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-to-drawable-in-android

Comment: Hola, ya lo hice y sigue igual.. No consigo mostrar la imagen..

Comment: tal vez ya sea un poco tardado la respuesta, pero a otros puede servirle para que el método que comente arriba funcione es necesario que tu imagen sea de tipo byte array